# Disable service worker in <Iframe>

Tags: iframe, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I need to disable service workers in `<iframe>`

I build offline PWAs for clients and have a number of demo PWAs running for my potential clients to test on their devices. I also wish to put these PWAs on my website in iframes, but when I do this, the viewer receives a browser notification stating that the app is installed on their device. This causes some alarm because the viewer might not be expecting this as they click through my website. I want to display the apps in an iframe without service worker activation, and with links inviting them to open the app in a new tab which they can then get the full PWA experience if they wish.

Thanks.